# How to stop Delphi IDE to generate .vlb file

Tags: delphi, livebindings

`.vlb` files store visual Live Bindings data.

Previously, my Delphi project never touched visual live bindings.  Whenever I saved a form, the IDE didn't generate a `.vlb` file.

Recently, I clicked on the 'Bind Visually...' option on one of my forms in the project.  A `.vlb` file keeps being created when I save other forms that do not have any Live Bindings settings.

I am using Delphi XE4.  Is there any option to turn off generation of the `.vlb` files for projects that do not use visual Live Bindings?

Comment: http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=115436

Comment: I had the same problem. It's annoying.

Comment: It's probably a setting in the .dproj file. I'd create a blank project, save the .dproj file, then "activate" live bindings as you did, and diff the new .proj file with the old one.

Comment: For me it was as easy as closing the Live Bindings panel, exiting Delphi (v10.2.3), then I deleted the .vlb file.  When I ran Delphi again, and edited/saved a project file, it did not recreate the .vlb files (like it did consistently until I restarted Delphi).

Comment: The link of bummi does not open any website. I need the answer. Pleeeeaaassseeee.